# Why on submitting form with image as file, my $_FILES array returns Array() empty array and my image is not stored on desired folder after submit

Tags: php, file-extension, move-uploaded-file

I have almost filled up this signup form 30 times in a day debugging this and still the image is not reaching to the destination folder as it should.
This code is present in htdocs/Email/signup.php and uploaded file should be moved to htdocs/gid113/Eagleeye/guard/imges/id.jpg  and even only "id." is inserted in mysql database and not "id.jpg" unable to get the extension for image .

```
    if(isset($_POST['signup'])){
        $result = $conn->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'guard'");
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id = $data['Auto_increment'];
        $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
        print_r($_FILES);

        // File Image handling while signup
        if($_FILES['img']['error']==UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
            $file_name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
            $file_size = $_FILES['img']['size'];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
            $file_type = $_FILES['img']['type'];
            $destination = "../gid113/Eagleeye/guard/imges/".basename($file_name);
            $file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$destination);
            // $new_name ="./imges/".$id.".".$file_extension;
            $new_name = id.".".$file_extension;
            rename($destination,$new_name);
            // $img=pathinfo($new_name,PATHINFO_BASENAME);
            $img=$new_name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>`?

Comment: Yes, i do have it

Comment: You should check `if (isset($_FILES['img']))` so you don't use nonexistent array elements.

Comment: If you check the Network panel of DevTools does it show the file being uploaded?

Comment: Sure, let me try

Comment: Yes, it is showing full green line in netwrork panel and when i enter otp it inserts "id." in database and file is not moved "jpg" is not fetched throufh PATH_EXTENSION somehow

Comment: Not sure what the green line is, but did you check the parameters being sent?

Comment: You said `$_FILES` is empty, so of course nothing is being returned through `PATHINFO_EXTENSION` -- there's no `$file_name`.

Comment: no i didn't see anything like that just the line nothing else

Comment: You have to click on the URL, it will open up nested tabs showing the headers, response, etc.

Comment: Okay let me check

Comment: omg i've not written $ in $new_name = $id

Comment: You should have gotten a PHP warning about there not being a constant named `id`. Make sure you enable warnings when you're debugging.

Comment: This $ made file name correct as id.jpg in mysql but the file is still not moved in the folder and also i have used isset()  so file is uploaded just fine

Comment: If the file were uploaded just fine, why would `print_r($_FILES)` show an empty array?

Comment: Now it works perfectly well... Thanks bud 

Answer (score 1):

*SOLUTION:-*

1. Added $ before Id in $new_name declaration.
2. Specified path to destination folder to the second parameter of rename as well.

```
if(isset($_FILES['img'])){
                $file_name = $_FILES['img']['name'];
                $file_size = $_FILES['img']['size'];
                $file_tmp = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
                $file_type = $_FILES['img']['type'];
                $destination = "../gid113/Eagleeye/guard/imges/".basename($file_name);
                $file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$destination);
                // $new_name ="./imges/".$id.".".$file_extension;
                $new_name = $id.".".$file_extension;
                rename($destination,"../gid113/Eagleeye/guard/imges/".$new_name);
                // $img=pathinfo($new_name,PATHINFO_BASENAME);
                $img=$new_name;
}
```

Comment: You should explain what was changed in your code to achieve the desired result.